# Деплой WAR'ника в Tomcat'e

Tags: java, tomcat

Запускал всегда приложение через `IntellijIDEA` и все было в порядке. Сегодня решил WAR'ник запустить из самого tomcat'a своими руками. После всех процедур открываю страницу и ловлю 404 ошибку ...

> The requested resource is not available.

Google подсказал внести изменения в файл web.xml (tomcat'овский файл):

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>views/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Где `views/index.html` это путь до индекс файла. После этого главная страница стала отображаться, но любой запрос выбрасывает предыдущую 404 ошибку. Вот конфиги:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebMvcConfig.class);
        ctx.register(DatabaseConfig.class);
        ctx.register(SecurityConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/*");

    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: запускате через run as или делаете именно деплой в самом томкате ?

Comment: @trembling11 деплой в томкате, если правильно понял. Через startup.bat